# how launch a Perl script from python

Tags: python, perl, subprocess

Basicaly, I would like to launch the perl script and use it as a python fonction in my programme.

My perl script contain an user input

```html
use strict;
use warnings;

print "\nCan you hear me ? (1/0) ";

my $choice = <STDIN>;
if ($choice == 1){
    print "\nYES";
}
```

I tried to us subprocess.run and subprocess.Popen with no success.

With subprocess.run, it print but doesn't wait the user's input.

PS: First post I something is missing just tell me ;)

Comment: you could, like, add your python side of things too ?

Comment: subprocess.run works fine in my environ.  just `subprocess.run(["perl", "test.pl"])`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os

output = os.popen('perl filename.pl').read()
```

It assign everything to 'output' except the user input, but you can always print out that again inside the perl script and then it will work.